# Tengo Un error en Mi Aplcacion de Angular con Firebase no se que es

Tags: angular, firebase

un error en en servicio de Firebase con angular dejo el link de mi repositorio en github
https://github.com/LaureanoBentanco/control-clientes
y una captura del error no se que pudeda ser que lo cause
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error exacto que muestra la consola es este:
La propiedad 'id' no existe en el tipo 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'.

Comment: Hola!, es más fácil leer código. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: También agrega el error que genera la consola. La forma más fácil de solucionar un problema es aislarlo por completo.

Comment: Las preguntas son autocontenidas. No debe depender de que tu cuenta o repositorio exista. Sobre todo para los que, en el futuro, tengan el mismo problema. Por favor, incluye el código relevante EN tu pregunta.

Comment: Al parecer no has definido `id` en el modelo de `doc`.

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden visualizar las imágenes.

Comment: aunque no puede compilar tu aplicacion por mostrar errores en los imports? con respecto a firebase si como mostras funciona proba  this.clientesColleccion.snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(
      (clienteSnapshot)=>
      {
    clienteSnapshot.forEach((clientData)=>{
      console.log('cliente data',clientData.payload.doc.data().id);
    })})

Comment: y decime que paso saludos